# C stack usage with temporary structures

Tags: c, stack

I work with embedded stuff, so, I use special C compiler C30 for MCUs. I'm confused about its behavior with temporary structures.

But, maybe I don't know something, and it's intended behavior?

Consider little code:

```
typedef struct {
   int a;
   int b;
} T_TestStruct1;

void test1(T_TestStruct1 *p_test_struct)
{
   /* do something */
}
```

And these calls to `test1()` :

```
void some_function()
{

   {
      T_TestStruct1 par = {
         .a = 1,
         .b = 1,
      };
      test1(&par);
   }

   {
      T_TestStruct1 par = {
         .a = 2,
         .b = 2,
      };
      test1(&par);
   }

}
```

Everything is OK here: just one instance of `T_TestStruct1` is allocated in the stack. But I like to use shorter expressions:

```
void some_function()
{
   test1(&(T_TestStruct1){
      .a = 1,
      .b = 1,
      });

   test1(&(T_TestStruct1){
      .a = 2,
      .b = 2,
      });
}
```

Then, both structures `{.a = 1, .b = 1}` and `{.a = 2, .b = 2}` are allocated in the stack. But, in my opninion, they should not be. Only one instance is actually needed.

Just by chance, I tried that:

```
void some_function()
{
   {
      test1(&(T_TestStruct1){
         .a = 1,
         .b = 1,
         });
   }

   {
      test1(&(T_TestStruct1){
         .a = 2,
         .b = 2,
         });
   }
}
```

Result is the same.

So, is it intended behavor, or is it a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Shouldn't you allow for a third possibility: that the exact behaviour will be undefined?

Comment: @Tommy, well, it is most likely undefined in standards, but in order to optimize memory usage (this is **really** important on embedded stuff), there should be just one instance. Or, is there reasons for compiler to allocate both structures?

Comment: I think that your compiler hasn't taken into consideration optimisation of compound literal allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't see the benefit of the expression causing you troubles. It makes the code just less readable.

But apart from that: You can't predict whether the compiler creates a stackframes including two instances of the structure or not. This is up to the compiler and his optimization engine. In case you really need control about the allocation of memory here and you really need to optimize, I'd suggest to allocate this variable once and explicitly reuse it for both calls, leaving a comment why you do it like this.

Comment: Thanks. But, to me, it isn't "less readable". By the way, if called function should return the value, then I need to allocate variable for returned value, then open `{ ... }` block, and assign value inside it. This is annoying.

Comment: @DmitryFrank Maybe it's not to you but maybe it's for others. The possibility that you won't maintain the code forever and someone else has to maintain your code later should be considered. You should also reconsider your stack assignment. Maybe it would be better to allocate a bit more stack so such tweaks are not necessary.

Comment: Well, consider these two examples: http://goo.gl/AQuEJ (there are 'variant A' and 'variant B'). Is variant B really more readable for "others", including you?  For me, in variant A, it's pretty clear that variable `value` is assigned to something returned by `some_function()`. But, in variant B, I need to read the whole block to understand what happened there.

Comment: @DmitryFrank Well for me it would be variant B. Maybe it's longer but it's clearer. But that's a question of taste I think. So it's not worth fighting about it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee (in the C standard) that your non-volatile variables will exist at all in the compiled code after all optimizations. Likewise there's no guarantee that your compiled code is the fastest and the smallest and uses the minimum amount of resources (that includes the stack).

If this is something critical for you, you could either play with the optimization options of your compiler or write this code in assembly (inline or not).