# Passing several flags and small enums as a function argument: hand-made int bitmasks or small struct?

Tags: c, struct, enums, flags

I work with embedded stuff (PIC), and in all the C codes I've seen, if function takes several flags or little enumerated values, it is done as hand-made int bitmasks, like that:

```
/* first flag */
#define  MY_FIRST_FLAG              (1 << 0)

/* second flag */
#define  MY_SECOND_FLAG             (1 << 1)

/*
 * some param that could have three variants
 */
#define  __MY_TRISTATE_OFFSET       2
#define  __MY_TRISTATE_MASK         (0x03 << __MY_TRISTATE_OFFSET)
#define  MY_TRISTATE_ONE            (0 << __MY_TRISTATE_OFFSET)
#define  MY_TRISTATE_TWO            (1 << __MY_TRISTATE_OFFSET)
#define  MY_TRISTATE_THREE          (2 << __MY_TRISTATE_OFFSET)

/* third flag */
#define  MY_THIRD_FLAG              (1 << 4)



void my_func(int opts)
{
   if (opts & MY_FIRST_FLAG){
      /* ... */
   }

   switch (opts & __MY_TRISTATE_MASK){
      case MY_TRISTATE_ONE:
         /* ... */
         break;
      case MY_TRISTATE_TWO:
         /* ... */
         break;
      case MY_TRISTATE_THREE:
         /* ... */
         break;
      default:
         /* error! */
         break;
   }

   /* ... */
}
```

But I don't like this "geek" approach too much:

- There's no type safety at compile time at all, one could mistakenly do the following: `my_func(MY_TRISTATE_ONE | MY_TRISTATE_TWO);` and it will compile.
- Again, type safety: if we have another function with different flags, we can freely pass flags for another function, and compiler won't help here;
- It's easy to make mistake while defining all these flags; if we need to add more flags or params, we should be very careful not to mix up offset stuff.
- What if one day our tristate should become some 5-state variable? Then, we should change its mask, and also change offsets of all params that go after. If we make a mistake here, nobody helps us. So, if something goes wrong, we should review that part of code over and over.

The only advantage of this approach is binary compatibility: data is organized in exactly the same way on all platforms, so, different devices/programs could communicate with this interface. But, for me, it's almost always out of concern: most of the code works just in one particular device, no need to keep binary compatibility with other world.

So, to me, it looks much better to define a small struct:

```
enum my_tristate_e {
   MY_TRISTATE_ONE,
   MY_TRISTATE_TWO,
   MY_TRISTATE_THREE,
};

struct my_func_opts_s {
   unsigned             my_first_flag  : 1;
   unsigned             my_second_flag : 1;
   enum my_tristate_e   my_tristate    : 2;
   unsigned             my_third_flag  : 1;
};


void my_func(struct my_func_opts_s opts)
{
   if (opts.my_first_flag){
      /* ... */
   }

   switch (opts.my_tristate){
      case MY_TRISTATE_ONE:
         /* ... */
         break;
      case MY_TRISTATE_TWO:
         /* ... */
         break;
      case MY_TRISTATE_THREE:
         /* ... */
         break;
      default:
         /* error! */
         break;
   }

   /* ... */
}
```

Advantages of that approach:

- We can't mistakenly give another struct to `my_func` (say, we have another struct with options for another function), compiler will generate an error if we try;
- We don't have to dig into all of the offsets stuff; compiler does that for us: so, we can't make a mistake here;
- If one day our tristate becomes 5-state variable and we forgot to change field width from `2` to `3`, compiler will warn us that field is too narrow;
- Since compiler is free to implement these bit fields as it sees fit, it is likely that   it will generate more optimized code on any platform.

Again, this approach won't work if we need program to be binary compatible, but it is almost always out of concern.

One would probably argue that calling that function looks too vastly: in the case of int flags, we have:

```
my_func(MY_TRISTATE_TWO | MY_FIRST_FLAG);
```

But in case of struct:

```
my_func2((struct my_func_opts_s){
      .my_first_flag = true,
      .my_tristate   = MY_TRISTATE_TWO,
      });
```

But anyway, strong type safety is worth typing, in my opinion. And, after all, sometimes I even like the second way more, because this code is more self-documented.

I've checked generated MIPS disassembly in both cases (well, I had to change functions a bit in order to make them do something, otherwise they are optimized out by the compiler), and generated code is almost identical (Optimization is `-Os` which is very often the case in the embedded world) :

- [actual code](http://goo.gl/o1xYu0),
- [generated MIPS disassembly](http://goo.gl/Yt07Zp).

But, this approach is never (or almost never) used. Why? Have I missed something important?

Comment: Do you know you could use an `enum` instead of `#define` to get some type safety?

Comment: @AndréSassi I know I can use `enum`, and I sometimes do this for a kind of code readability, but as far as I know there's no type safety I can benefit from it: I can easily do bitwise `OR` on elements from different enums, or mix enum values and macros together, and compiler will silently allow this. What type safety are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disadvantage of using bitfields in a `struct` is that you cannot write the the flags directly at the function call unless you have access to "compound literals" from C99.

Lets say you have a bitfield that looks like this:

```
struct bit_field {
    unsigned int a:1;
    unsigned int b:1;
    unsigned int c:1;
    unsigned int d:1;
};
```

And a function that uses the bitfield that is declared like this:

```
void use_bit_field(struct bit_field a);
```

If you are writing in C99 you can write the function call the way you did:

```
use_bit_field((struct bit_field){
    .a = 1,
    .b = 0,
    .c = 1,
    .d = 0
});
```

Which looks very good! But for this to work we need to be able to use "compound literals" which is a C99 feature. You probably already know that C99 unfortunately is not as widely available as C89 is.

People who don't have access to C99 must write the function call like this:

```
struct bit_field bits = {
    1, 1, 0, 1 // EDIT: Initializing the struct step by step is alot less error prone (mentioned in the comments).
};

/* ... */

use_bit_field(bits);
```

Which some people would argue is alot less clear than:

```
use_bit_field(BITFIELD_A | BITFIELD_B | BITFIELD_D);
```

But ofcourse it is just a matter of preference.

Another disadvantage is that you loose the opportunity to preform bit operations on the bitfield.

You cannot write:

```
if (bit_field1 & bit_field2)
```

To check if two bitfields both have the same bit turned on. 
You must instead write an ugly cast:

```
if (*(int8_t *)&bit_field1 & *(int8_t *)&bit_field2)
```

These are the disadvantages I could think of. I personally still think that defining bitfields in a `struct` is the superior approach.

Comment: `struct bit_field bits = { 1, 1, 0, 1 };` is totally not acceptable: it is much more error-prone than plain bit masks. What if order of field changes some day? It could lead to really hard-to-catch bugs, one day I already had to deal with exactly such bug. If we haven't `C99`, it's much better to init step-by-step, like: `struct bit_field bits = {};  bits.a = 1; bits.b = 1; /*etc*/`. It does not looks perfect, but much more stable. But, luckily, C99 is present in most compilers these days, even in modern embedded Microchip compilers that tend to be crappy. So I wouldn't care about non-C99.

Comment: In the case you're interested: check out my own answer to this question, unfortunately I found serious gcc-related drawback of using the structure instead of int bitmask.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I found serious gcc-related drawback of using the structure instead of int bitmask: when optimization is 0, each call to such a function takes **much** more stack.

Optimization 0 is sometimes useful if we need to debug something.

I work with embedded stuff (PIC32 these days), compiler for PIC32 is based on gcc. When I turned off optimization, I got weird errors, after several hours of debugging I found out that it's because stack overflow: one function that passes little structure as a parameter many times, takes about 1400 bytes of stack. When optimization is `s`, it takes 300 bytes of stack.

So, when I've rewritten stuff so that `int` is passed instead of `struct`, the code generated with optimization 0 also takes 300 bytes of stack.

On embedded stuff RAM is vital, and optimization 0 is sometimes really useful, so, I had to stick to `int` approach for now, unfortunately.

Comment: That's news to me, interesting find. I don't know if that compiler supports gcc extensions but if it does: have you tried using `__attribute__((packed))` on the structure?

Comment: It does support that extension, but I don't think it would help. Maybe I'll try though, thanks. See my old question about structures at the stack, this is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807016/c-stack-usage-with-temporary-structures